# How to solve ClassNOtFound Error while using apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to generate a word doc using apache POI.But when i am trying to run that code i am getting ClassDefNotFound error.Here is my code upto what i have tried.

```
public class SimpleDocument {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFParagraph p1 = doc.createParagraph();
    p1.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
    p1.setBorderBottom(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p1.setBorderTop(Borders.DOUBLE);

    p1.setBorderRight(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p1.setBorderLeft(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p1.setBorderBetween(Borders.SINGLE);

    p1.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);

    XWPFRun r1 = p1.createRun();
    r1.setBold(true);
    r1.setText("The quick brown fox");
    r1.setBold(true);
    r1.setFontFamily("Courier");
    r1.setUnderline(UnderlinePatterns.DOT_DOT_DASH);
    r1.setTextPosition(100);

    XWPFParagraph p2 = doc.createParagraph();
    p2.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

    //BORDERS
    p2.setBorderBottom(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p2.setBorderTop(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p2.setBorderRight(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p2.setBorderLeft(Borders.DOUBLE);
    p2.setBorderBetween(Borders.SINGLE);

    XWPFRun r2 = p2.createRun();
    r2.setText("jumped over the lazy dog");
    r2.setStrike(true);
    r2.setFontSize(20);

    XWPFRun r3 = p2.createRun();
    r3.setText("and went away");
    r3.setStrike(true);
    r3.setFontSize(20);
    r3.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUPERSCRIPT);


    XWPFParagraph p3 = doc.createParagraph();
    p3.setWordWrap(true);
    p3.setPageBreak(true);

    //p3.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.DISTRIBUTE);
    p3.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.BOTH);
    p3.setSpacingLineRule(LineSpacingRule.EXACT);

    p3.setIndentationFirstLine(600);


    XWPFRun r4 = p3.createRun();
    r4.setTextPosition(20);
    r4.setText("To be, or not to be: that is the question: "
            + "Whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer "
            + "The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, "
            + "Or to take arms against a sea of troubles, "
            + "And by opposing end them? To die: to sleep; ");
    r4.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    r4.setText("No more; and by a sleep to say we end "
            + "The heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks "
            + "That flesh is heir to, 'tis a consummation "
            + "Devoutly to be wish'd. To die, to sleep; "
            + "To sleep: perchance to dream: ay, there's the rub; "
            + ".......");
    r4.setItalic(true);
//This would imply that this break shall be treated as a simple line break, and break the line    after that word:

    XWPFRun r5 = p3.createRun();
    r5.setTextPosition(-10);
    r5.setText("For in that sleep of death what dreams may come");
    r5.addCarriageReturn();
    r5.setText("When we have shuffled off this mortal coil,"
            + "Must give us pause: there's the respect"
            + "That makes calamity of so long life;");
    r5.addBreak();
    r5.setText("For who would bear the whips and scorns of time,"
            + "The oppressor's wrong, the proud man's contumely,");

    r5.addBreak(BreakClear.ALL);
    r5.setText("The pangs of despised love, the law's delay,"
            + "The insolence of office and the spurns" + ".......");

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("simple.docx");
    doc.write(out);
    out.close();

    }
}
```

And here is the Exception that i am getting while trying to run that code..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlException
at com.jeet.poi.SimpleDocument.main(SimpleDocument.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

Comment: why you don't try with my answer? it's really work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all list the jars you are placing in the class path.

I think you need following jar into you classpath

```
xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.4.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [XML beans dependency](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to your class path.

The library is usually called **xmlbeans-x.x.x.jar**

Comment: i have added xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar to my class path but still getting the same error

Comment: please add 2 more jar as my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ooxml-lib in your class path.

```
1) dom4j-1.6.1.jar
2) stax-api-1.0.1.jar
3) xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

I would recommend you to choose suitable ooxml-lib version for your apche-poi which are used in your project.